# 1980's tv series - awakened ancient man with a Phoenix medallion

Tags: story-identification, tv

This was definitely in the realm of sci-fi series:
I think title of series had the word Phoenix in it or the main character's powers or power came from a big gold medallion with an illustration of a Phoenix on it. It starts out with a body of an ancient man being dug up by some archaeologist on a dig site. He woke up, but then all I remember is he is always wandering or hitchhiking, kind of like the beginning and ending scene from the *Incredible Hulk* series in the 80's. One of the characters was a tall weird looking guy with long blonde hair, who drew some kind of power from his Phoenix medallion or something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[The Phoenix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phoenix_(1982_TV_series))*

[image: Picture of Bennu with medallion]

> The Phoenix is a 1982 television series starring Judson Scott which was on ABC for about one month. The plot revolved around an ancient extraterrestrial named Bennu of the Golden Light, who is discovered in a sarcophagus in Peru and awakened in the 20th Century. The series was preceded by a TV movie on April 26, 1981.

### The Pilot episode

Found by searching for *tv series phoenix medallion*