# 70s/80s movie about a telepathic visitor (either time traveler or extraterrestrial) with a connection to the pyramids trying to warn humans

Tags: story-identification, aliens, telepathy

It's a movie I saw as a youngster. If I remember correctly it was about a visitor - he looked Caucasian perhaps from Norway/Sweden/Finland.  Can't remember if he was a time traveler or extraterrestrial.  I think an E.B.E.  with a direct link to or special focus on the pyramids and I think he wore a light-material white clothing. I think he was trying to help mankind or reveal something to mankind but some group was trying to stop him. When he needed to convey complex info to the people he made contact with, he used telepathy, and in the movie sometimes this was illustrated by various symbols/geometric shapes passing from his forehead into the forehead of the person he was passing the information to. I think the movie ended in a sad and mysterious way because the movie evoked emotions (similar to the movie about the young lady & giant turtle from the 80s) and memories of the movie are accompanied by nostalgia.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168951/1980s-tv-series-awakened-ancient-man-with-a-phoenix-medallion

Answer (score 5):

## *The Phoenix*

This sounds like the TV movie [*The Phoenix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phoenix_(1982_TV_series)) (1981), which led into the 1982 TV series of the same name.  The titular character is an ancient alien astronaut named Bennu, who looks like a blond human man.  In modern times, Bennu awakens from suspended animation knowing that he has a mission to guide humanity's development.  He uses his advanced mental powers to attempt to find his partner so that they can begin the mission.

> When he needed to convey complex info to the people he made contact with, he used telepathy, and in the movie sometimes this was illustrated by various symbols/geometric shapes passing from his forehead into the forehead of the person he was passing the information to.

You can see this effect at 23:17 in the pilot movie:

See also: [1980's tv series - awakened ancient man with a Phoenix medallion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168951/1980s-tv-series-awakened-ancient-man-with-a-phoenix-medallion/168952#168952)

Comment: Yes. The geometric shapes mentioned in the question can be seen in the movie at [23:17](https://youtu.be/JvqGS4qrvkg?t=23m17s).

Comment: @MrLister — Thanks! I've added that clip per your suggestion.